# Request.ServerVariables() for Shibboleth in .NET 6

Tags: .net-6.0, shibboleth

I am trying to use Shibboleth on a site that uses .NET 6. The Shibboleth documentation uses `Request.ServerVariables()` but when I add that, I get the error "HttpRequest does not contain a definition for 'ServerVariables'".

I instantiated an `IServerVariablesFeature` object and I can get the `SERVER_NAME` variable from there, but I can't find any Shibboleth variables like `Shib-Application-ID`. Is my `IServerVariablesFeature` the right place to look for the Shibboleth variables or do I need to get `Request.ServerVariables()` to work?

By visiting https://domain/Shibboleth.sso/Session I can see the session information, so I know that the authentication is working correctly, I'm just trying to access the user information from an application.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: what variable are you trying to get specifically? Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"].ToString() should return the current users sam.

Comment: @JobesK The one I specifically need is the ePPN, but I can't find any of them.

Comment: try referencing this https://serverfault.com/questions/640240/shibboleth-does-pass-attribute-to-server-variable-in-php

Comment: @JobesK Thanks for the suggestion. I can't find anything on `.htaccess` or `conf.d` for Windows. I already have the `RequireSession` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IServerVariablesFeature serverVariables = HttpContext.Features.Get<IServerVariablesFeature>();` works, as does `HttpContext.GetServerVariable("VARIABLE_NAME");`. What I was missing is that these variables are only available to pages that are protected by Shibboleth. I added the path for my page to the shibboleth2.xml file and I could see the variables.